# Using SAP OpenUI5 on .NET business apps

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sapui5

Currently, I find that it seems to be possible to convert existing .NET business application to use OpenUI5 when the user interface coding is completely isolated from the application logic by using the ASP.net view engine, "Razor".  Please see the link below.

http://www.konkconsulting.com/EN/Articles/Article_openui5_net

I followed the steps, and here is my implementation:

Test.cshtml:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Models

<script src="~/Views/Home/Test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     new WebAppView_RootLayoutMenu();
</script>
```

Test.js

```
function WebAppView_RootLayoutMenu() {
"use strict";


window.sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
    //Create openUi5 components here & add them to the HTML body

       var oimage = new sap.m.Image("asd", { src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/GEO_Globe.jpg" });


});
}
```

some problems I have encountered:

1. In Test.js, I don't know to how put the openui items into the html page
2. In Test.js, "var oimage = new sap.m.Image(...)", with the error:

   > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined
3. from the website, in the Test.cshtml, the implementation is like "window.WebAppManager.RootLayoutMenu = new WebAppView_RootLayoutMenu();" What is "window.WebAppManager.RootLayoutMenu"? With this setting, it is not working..

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Angus

Answer (score 1):

OpenUI5 using oData protocol for standard. You can check oData service sample for C#. You don't need razor. You will create static OpenUI5 js app and this app commincate with C# over rest services with protocol oData.
Note: Also you can use UI5 framework without oData. But this option need a lot of custom development for two side.

You can check my ui5 demo site which is working with nodejs: http://ui5.mkysoft.com/

Also we develop commercial app with it using C# without oData: https://emutabakattest.isisbilisim.com.tr/

Comment: I've upvoted this answer, but only because my own research on this question agrees with with mkysoft, rather than that I have any expertise. I've also upvoted the question; it has been downvoted without comment, which I think is wrongful.